# Better combat logs?

Tags: eve-online

Is there any way to customise/change the way that combat logs in eve are displayed?

At the moment, I tend to miss all of the details of combat in large battles.. eg, when I'm fighting a group of 10 NPCs, I have 5 drones deployed and am firing 4 weapon groups, you can't see any of the relevant combat details.

Best case scenario, I'd like to be able to view all those details in a list with a scrollbar.

Comment: It seems like EVE would be a much better game with a customizable UI (a la WoW), or at least one designed by someone with some UX experience, rather than just being purdy/futuristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a great feature, but as far as I know, you cannot customize the combat log.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to check out the log file parser at http://www.eve-log.com/. This might do what you want it to, and doesn't require extra software to be installed.